# How to define scrapy items dynamically

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to pass this class to scrapy Itemloader.
I know this class is wrong, But how can do it?

```
class DummyItem(scrapy.Item):

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
        super(DummyItem, self).__init__()

    self.num = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: Why not use Item, and use `item_loader.add_value('num', num)`? Support for dynamic items was removed when it became possible to yield dictionaries instead of item classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `ItemLoader` and `DummyItem` item in the spider, and then initialize the item loader with your item class.

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from myproject.items import DummyItem

def parse(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(item=DummyItem(), response=response)
    l.add_xpath('num', '//div[@class="product_num"]')
    return l.load_item()
```

If you are declaring your own `ItemLoader`, you can specify `default_item_class` as follow:

```
class DummyItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = DummyItem
```